# Distinction between a vector and a tensor of type (1,0)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let's say I have a differentiable manifold $\mathscr{M}$. A vector $v$ on this manifold is a map from $\mathscr{F}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathscr{F}$ is the set of all smooth functions from $\mathscr{M}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. A tensor of type (1,0) is a map from $V^{\ast}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which we identify as a vector (because $V^{\ast\ast}$ is isomorphic to $V$). So how do we make this association, between a map that takes an element from $V^{\ast}$ and gives a number, to a map that takes an element from $\mathscr{F}$ and gives a number? Does that mean $V^{\ast}$ and $\mathscr{F}$ are isomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear I'm letting $V$ denote the space of vectors at a single point $p$.

The pairing is very natural - given a vector $v \in V$, it acts as an element of $V^{**}$ by $v(\theta) = \theta(v)$ for any $\theta\in V^*$; and any element of $V^{**}$ turns out to act in exactly this way for some $v$. This is true for any finite-dimensional vector space - there's nothing to do with the action of $V$ on $\mathscr F$ here.

There is a sense in which $\mathscr F$ acts on $V$, of course - just "flip" the usual action, so $f(v) = v(f)$. For each $f \in \mathscr F$ this is a linear map $V \to \mathbb R$, so each $f$ produces an element $df_p \in V^*$; but different functions can produce the same map! (These are exactly the functions that agree with $f$ to first order at $p$.) Thus we have a map $\mathscr F \to V^*$, but it is certainly not an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! So to be very explicit, If I have a vector $v$, it takes an element $f\in\mathscr{F}$ as an argument. Viewed as a (1,0) tensor $T$, it has to take an element of $V^{\ast}$ as an argument, which (in terms of $f$) we can write as $w\mapsto w(f) \,\,\,\in V^{\ast}$. Conversely, if I am given a tensor T of type (1,0), it takes as an argument $\theta\in V^{\ast}$. How do I express this $\theta$ as an element of $\mathscr{F}$?

Comment: @Psycho_pr: choose any function $f \in \mathscr F$ such that $df_p = \theta$. In coordinates such a function would look like e.g. $f(p+x) = \sum_i \theta_i x^i$. Then $\theta(v) = df_p(v) = v(f)$.